# Evaluation of limit using definition of derivative

Tags: limits, derivatives

[image]
From image
How to solve such cases and whether we can write derivative of function in that manner

Answer (score 1):

Let ${\epsilon}$ be defined by

$$f \left(a+h\right) = f \left(a\right)+h {f'} \left(a\right)+h {\epsilon} \left(h\right)$$

so that ${\epsilon} \left(h\right) \rightarrow  0$ when $h \rightarrow  0$. Let us define

$${\mu} \left(h\right) = {\sup }_{t \in  \left[0 , h\right]} \left|{\epsilon} \left(t\right)\right|$$

so that ${\mu} \left(h\right)$ is monotononic increasing and ${\mu} \left(h\right) \rightarrow  0$ when $h \rightarrow  0$.
Finally, let

$${S}_{n} = \sum _{k = 1}^{n} \left(f \left(a+\frac{k}{{n}^{2}}\right)-f \left(a\right)\right) = \sum _{k = 1}^{n} \left(\frac{k}{{n}^{2}} {f'} \left(a\right)+\frac{k}{{n}^{2}} {\epsilon} \left(\frac{k}{{n}^{2}}\right)\right)$$

Using $\sum _{k = 1}^{n} k = \frac{n \left(n+1\right)}{2}$, we obtain

$$\left|{S}_{n}-\frac{n \left(n+1\right)}{2 {n}^{2}} {f'} \left(a\right)\right| = \left|\sum _{k = 1}^{n} \frac{k}{{n}^{2}} {\epsilon} \left(\frac{k}{{n}^{2}}\right)\right|  \leqslant  {\mu} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \sum _{k = 1}^{n} \frac{k}{{n}^{2}} = {\mu} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \frac{n \left(n+1\right)}{2 {n}^{2}}$$

Hence

$$\left|{S}_{n}-\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) {f'} \left(a\right)\right|  \leqslant  \frac{1}{2} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) {\mu} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \rightarrow  0$$

Hence

$${\lim }_{n \rightarrow  \infty } {S}_{n} = \frac{1}{2} {f'} \left(a\right)$$

Comment: Thank you sir but I haven't studied real analysis till so please tell me how to solve using definition of differentiation

Comment: The definition of differentiation is that the quantity $\epsilon(h) = \frac{f(a+h)- f(a)}{h} - f^\prime(a)$ tends to $0$ when $h$ tends to $0$. I used nothing else.